# How to enable full retranslation of an RCP app when changing the language with start parameter?

Tags: eclipse, internationalization, swt, translation, rcp

I have the following Problem. When I start my RCP Application(e3) in a differen language other than on first start, all declarative Translations, such as defined in plugin.xml files (%Somelabel) are cached and stay in the old language.

Is there any possibility to change this behaviur without clearing the whole configuration space.

Best Regards Matthias

Comment: This should just be automatic. How are you specifying the locale?

Comment: on start as Commandline parameter -nl en_EN for example. If i had previous started with -nl de_DE some translations still stay in German(those from the plugIn.xml files)